# Undefined property: FieldCollectionItemEntity::

Tags: 7

> Notice: Undefined property: FieldCollectionItemEntity::$field_wa_thick
>   in _get_details() (line 385 of ...../er.module).
>
> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null
>   given in _get_details()

The error is on the following line:

```
$wt = ((array_key_exists('und',$li[$li_id]->field_wa_thick))?$li[$li_id]->field_wa_thick['und'][0]['value'] : NULL );
```

What may be the reason for the following error above??

Comment: You're not ACTUALLY asking anything here. Perhaps you could edit some more information into this question.

Comment: Welcome to drupal answers. Please review the http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By allowing only if the value is set the error disappeared.

```
if (isset($li[$li_id]->field_wa_thick['und']) {
  $wt = $li[$li_id]->field_wa_thick['und'][0]['value'];
}
```

Also applying the isset if the value is used elsewhere.